# PyCharm Code Folding Collapse

Tags: python, colors, ide, pycharm, setting

In PyCharm, I have it selected in my settings so that when I collapse the code within a method or I collapse my import statements, I get the box on the left hand size by the line numbers with the "+" inside it to expand when I want to investigate.

Is there any way to adjust the color settings in PyCharm regarding that expansion box with the "+" so that is stands out better? On my Mac it stands out just fine and I can always find them, but on my Windows machine (using a very similar if not the same Darcula color settings .jar) the boxes blend in too perfectly with the background of the script and I have trouble finding them. I am not sure if it is that the box is not outlined properly, or if the colors prevent me from seeing the outline at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to use the **keyboard shortcuts** for (un-)folding. They are very helpful and maybe you can have a look. I also sometimes click "in the code" to fold or unfold code.

If that does not solve your problem, intelliJ comes with 3 different default **UI themes** (Darcula, GTK+, IntelliJ on linux) that you can change in Settings > Appearance > Theme. Maybe you can switch to another theme.

If they're not what you need, you can also download **custom theme plugins** such as: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006?pr= . Perhaps "material black" which is close to "darkula" can render your buttons a bit more clearly.

Or, you can also **define custom themes** to change only the plus button (as it's an "appearance" setting, not syntax highlighting, you can't easily change the color or the shape of that specific button). It's more hard than the two previous solutions (as it involves creating a custom plugin), but you can pick one from github and just change the icon you need. https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/tree/master/resources/icons could be a good starting point

Comment: Also was able to change the colors associated with the gutter area to better illustrate the difference. Thanks!